# Why can't I change "Catalog Price Scope" to "Website"

Tags: magento-2.1, configuration, scope

Using Magento 2.1.5, I am trying to change the `Catalog Price Scope` option to `Website` from `Global` in `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Price`, but I cannot as it is disabled.

I have got 2 websites, each with one store and one store view.

Can someone help explain why I cannot change this option under the `Default Config` section for the scope. If I change the scope to anything else, I don't even see the option (which makes sense).

[image: Config]
[image: Scope]

Comment: I've just upgraded to CE v2.1.6 and the issue is the same there.

Comment: Do you have any custom extensions that might touch the catalog module? I didn't find anything that might make the field disabled.

Comment: Thanks @Marius we have a few extensions installed, but none that I think should affect this. We have the BoostMyShop ERP and Infortis theme, but nothing else and I don't see how these should affect the catalog module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check env.php for config setting overrides. I suspect you might have something like below in your env.php

```
'system' =>
    array(
        'default' =>
            array(
                'catalog' =>
                    array(
                        'price' =>
                            array(
                                'scope' => 0
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, this solved it. It was actually in `app/etc/config.local.php` and I could change the value there, or comment out the section completely and then make the changes within the admin panel. Really appreciate the help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `Stores > Configuration > General > Single-Store Mode` is set to `Yes`. If so change it to `No`.

Comment: I don't think this is it. When single store mode is enabled you cannot even see the product price scope dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, but @Marius is right, it is set to "No".

Comment: @Marius true but this was the only element I could find that changes something in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a staging site available? You can test if can change/add the value to the core_config_data table, that might solve it.

Also maybe this is caused by a third module. You can check all the modules via the command line with `php bin/magento module:status` and then disable all the third party modules with `php bin/magento module:disable module_name` and see if this solves your problem.

Both measures should be not be tried on live shops.